# How to create empty Qt project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Using visual studio C++ 2010 Ult.
I have compiled and instaled Qt libraries and visual studio add-in is installed into VC++ so I'm basicaly able to build Qt applications using Qt templates ofered from VS add-in.
I'm also able to include Qt headers and all works just fine...

installation has been done using VSC++ command promt, full build using
configure and nmake then.

QTDIR and PATH are properly seted up.
Qt libs are installed into:
(QTDIR) C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Libraries\Qt
(PATH)  C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Libraries\Qt\bin

BIG BUT:
when crating new empty(or other non Qt template) project I can't include any Qt header so my question is how to enable this.

I want to set this so I can in all my future projects simply write:

```
#include <Qapplication>
#include <Qlabel> //etc...
```

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the user properties for that? Set up the include and library paths there, then you should have Qt available for all projects.

See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx

Comment: thanks, Qt templates do not include anything in that dialog tools->options->project and solutions->VC++Directories->"include directories", so I thought it's not necesary to do that for other projects since visual studio add-in does not do so and it still works. so is there any other way to do this for all future projects like VS add-in does do it?

Comment: thanks, my problem was I didn't inluce libraries via "project_name"->"propertypages"->linker->input->library dependencies and linker->adidtional library paths... now it rocks :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason VS can't find Qt headers. I think the only possibility is that you have not specified Qt include paths in the project (not for VS, just for a project). VS add-in always specifies these paths according to the user settings. The basic ones are ($(QTDIR)\include), $(QTDIR)\include\QtCore and $(QTDIR)\include\QtGui. The last one is necessary only when creating non-console GUI applications.

Comment: thanks for reply, I've included everything and still not finding headers, also included libraries in "addition library dependencies" no luck. same issuse with boost libs which I've build right now on my fresh installed windows. I'm going to kill my self ;_;